# Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong with Netmiko script

Tags: netmiko

```
     output4 = net_connect.send_command('show running-config')

     console_logging = False
     for line in output4.readlines():
        if line.startswith("logging"):
            console_logging = True
            break
        if console_logging:
            print('Logging console is enabled')
        else:
            print ('logging console is not enabled')

    net_connect.disconnect()
```

Trying to search the running config and then print whether that line is present or not. When I run this, I get  "attribute error: 'str object has no attribute "readlines"

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use as `for line in output.split("\n"):` Can you try as follow code:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

net_connect = ConnectHandler(
    device_type="cisco_ios",
    host="172.16.14.2",
    secret="cisco",
    username="cisco",
    password="cisco")
    
net_connect.enable()
output = net_connect.send_command('show running-config')

console_logging = False

for line in output.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith("logging"):
        console_logging = True
        break
if console_logging:
    print('Logging console is enabled')
else:
    print ('Logging console is not enabled')

net_connect.disconnect()
```